# Django, full state name from USStateField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When I try and access the variable initialized to a USStateField in Django, it gives me the two letter normalization.  I realize this is the behavior that Django intends but there must be some way to access the full name since Django can populate the menu with the full state names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 >>>from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import US_STATES
 >>>dict(US_STATES)['AL']
 'Alabama'
```